# How to call this from another class?

Tags: kotlin

I have following code:

```
object CommonUtil {
    fun Int.dp(): Int = (this / Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.density).toInt()
    fun Int.px(): Int = (this * Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.density).toInt()
}
```

While I can do this function inside that Object:

```
fun test() {
    10.dp()
}
```

Is it possible to do something like `CommonUtil.10.dp()` too from other class?

Answer (score 2):

You can do what you want like this:

```
with(CommonUtil) {
    10.dp()
}
```

Although you should consider other ways to design your function:

- Passing `Int` as a parameter, not as receiver:

  ```
  CommonUtil.dp(10)
  ```
- Declaring `Int.dp()` as a top-level function, if you don't need data from `CommonUtil` (like in your case), or if you can declare this data as `public` or `internal`:

  ```
  10.dp()
  ```

If your `CommonUtil` object doesn't store any data and just contains utilily functions, it's much better to get rid of this object and just make all its functions top-level.

For example, your `CommonUtil.kt` file may look like this:

```
fun Int.dp(): Int = (this / Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.density).toInt()
fun Int.px(): Int = (this * Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.density).toInt()
```

So you can write `10.dp()` anywhere in your code.

Comment: Sorry I don't really understand your last statement, do you mean I need to put it in my top activity class instead?

Comment: Do you have a simple example for it? That will be very helpful :)

Comment: I meant the same thing another answerer did. Updated my answer.

Comment: Ah yes! I have that 'CommonUtil.kt' file contains that code, so I was asking how to call it from my other classes (my custom view class specifically). So I guess my code structure is still fine hmm. Sorry I am just 2 days old in Kotlin lol and I used to code like this in Android's Java, but I found this extension as a new interesting thing.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to extend the functionality of Ints (say, in TargetModule.kt), promote the extension functions as top-level functions in the defining module and import them into the using module.  For example,

```
// CommonUtil.kt -- defining module
package commonutil
fun Int.dp(): Int = (this / Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.density).toInt()
fun Int.px(): Int = (this * Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.density).toInt()

// TargetModule.kt -- using module
import commonutil.dp
import commonutil.px
... 10.dp()
```

Comment: This works! I am still interested with the other person's answer statement though. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Extension functions should be defined as package-level functions. So, simply remove the CommonUtil object and place extension function directly in a Kotlin file.

```
fun Int.dp(): Int = (this / Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.density).toInt()
fun Int.px(): Int = (this * Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.density).toInt()
```

And, if you want to group all extension function and do not want to make those package-level function then check out this [discussion](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/declaring-extension-methods-in-a-class-object/1105). There are some temporary workarounds.